# ASP.NET inline expressions not working in CssClass attribute?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, web-controls

I have the following code:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
                CommandName="SwitchStep"
                CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>'
                CssClass="<%# some conditional code here %> activestep">
    Step <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Inline statements work in the `CommandArgument` attribute, and I know they work in the text attribute. For some reason, though, in the `CssClass` attribute, the inline statement ends up (unparsed) in the HTML output! What the hell?

In Chrome:

```
<a class="&lt;%= 'steptab' %&gt;" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("StepControl:_ctl1:_ctl0", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>
            Step 1: section_name</a>
```

Has anyone run into this before? I'm not sure why this shouldn't work. It doesn't seem logical, and I'm a little frustrated.

Some notes:

- If I put a character in here that doesn't belong, such as "?" (this is VB), the compiler complains.
- Any server tag (<%, <%#, etc) shows up in the HTML.
- This is inside a repeater control. Wait, that's in the code.
- If I remove the "activestep" class after the inline statement, the inline statement still appears, although at one time I didn't have a class attribute appearing in HTML at all.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you can write an Expression in `CssClass` property. Try this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
                CommandName="SwitchStep"
                CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>'
                CssClass="<%$ Iif(condition, "activestep", "") %>">
    Step <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

On the other hand, you could use `ItemDataBound` event handler to wrapper your condition and set the `CssClass` property on the control inside your Repeater. Take a look

In the WEbForm, add a reference to the ItemDataBound

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
...
</asp:Repeater>
```

### VB.NET

```
' This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.
Public Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) 

    ' Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
    if e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

        Dim p as Product = CType(e.Item.DataItem, Product) ' cast to your entity just a sample

        If p.Active Then ' check some condition     

            CType(e.Item.FindControl("Your_LinkButtonId"), LinkButton).CssClass = "activestep"

        End If
    End if

End Sub
```

### C#

```
// This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.
public void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
    // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
    {
        Product p = (Product)e.Item.DataItem; // cast to your entity just a sample

        if (p.Active) // check some condition
        {
            ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("Your_LinkButtonId")).CssClass = "activestep";
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but I was hoping not to have to add to the Codebehind. This means that I have to put an ID on my Linkbutton, and add a lot of code that really should be taken care of in one line. Although I'll probably take this route, do you know why the original solution isn't working?

Comment: I am not sure if you can write an expression on cssclass properyy. Take a look at my edits.

Answer (score 1):

You can build up the CssClass using `String.Format()`

```
CssClass='<%# String.Format("{0} activestep", If(condition, "truestring", "falsestring"))%>'>
```

Comment: To not create a If function in the backend, CssClass='<%# String.Format("{0} activestep", condition ? "truestring" : "falsestring")%>'>

Comment: @etlds That is c# but the question required vb.net.